# Laravel session json to sting in blade

Tags: php, laravel-5

im using Laravel 5.8.30

i set a session ,, when i call session in blade page

```
 {{Session::get('mydata')}}
```

its showing

```
[
   {
  "id": 2,
  "country_id": 18xxx
  "code": "vvv",
  "name": "vvvvvv",
  "shipping": "12345",
  "created_at": "2019-09-30 00:00:00",
  "updated_at": "2019-09-30 00:00:00"
 }
]
```

i got this output
i need to specific details in string .. how can i show this in my blade page 
only single value

thanks in advance :)

Comment: json_decode and simple foreach?

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
{{ json_decode( Session::get('mydata'), true )[ 'country_id' ] }}
```